# iOS social integration - Pragmatically show alert when no Facebook / Twitter account shows

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-framework

I do have sharing FB/Twitter in my app, using this code :

```
SLComposeViewController *vc = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
```

It works fine, when user doesn't have FB/Twitter, it prompt below alert :

[image]

Now, I do have Facebook integration / login. and I need to check first whether this particular device has Facebook account or not. my goes :

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
 {
   [self connectFB];
 }
  else{
    //show alert
 }
```

I want to show alert similar to what Social Framework was showing above. I can create alert my self, but I cannot direct user to go to Facebook Settings when user click on Settings button (not possible).

Is there any code to show pragmatically alert like above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot show it.  You can go ahead and popup the SLComposeViewController to send a message and it will display the alert, but then you will see the compose UI behind the alert, which may or may not be okay with you.

Comment: Yup, I don't want user to see compose UI behind. that's the issue. I just want to show alert. Thanks though. hopefully anyone can help other workaround.

Comment: You used to be able to walk the View tree and hide the compose UI, but they made it a [remote view](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/) in iOS 7 or 7.1, so you're out of luck.  And they shut down apps linking to settings many versions ago.